# Left Outer Join with one result per match and "priority" of match set by a different field in match SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, join, outer-join

I am trying to get a single result (PHONE) per match (CONTACT_ID) in a Left Outer Join. I imagine that there is a way to accomplish this with the preference (or order) being set by another column/field- the phone type (TYPE), but I haven't been able to figure it out. Below is a list of facts to help better explain what I am trying to accomplish and then following is an example Table A and B with the desired result. I've looked at min() and group by, but I don't know how to make those work here. As a side note, after this is working, I will be joining it to more tables to the left of it in a simpler fashion.

- The student can have an unlimited number of CONTACT_ID.
- A contact does not always have all phone types.
- The preferred order of phone types (TYPE) is C,H,W (which, fortunately, happens to be alphabetical)
- ignore match and go to the next in priority if PHONE is null

**TableA:**

```
STUDENT_ID  CONTACT_ID
----------  ----------
X           1
X           2
Y           3
Y           4
```

**TableB:**

```
CONTACT_ID    TYPE    PHONE
----------    ----    -----
1             H       21
1             C
1             W       44
2             H       78
2             C       92
2             W       11
```

**Desired Result:**

```
STUDENT_ID     CONTACT_ID   TYPE   PHONE
----------     ----------   ----   -----
X              1            H      21
X              2            C      92
Y              3
Y              4
```

Here is the query that I have that will make a join with all phone matches (minus all of my crazy attempts at getting what I want).

```
SELECT *
FROM Table TableA T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB T2 ON T1.CONTACT_ID = T2.CONTACT_ID
```

All help greatly appreciated!

**Edited code from Stefan Onofrei's solution:**

(results in some duplicate entries)

```
SELECT
    T1.STUDENT_ID,
    T1.CONTACT_ID,
    T2.PHONE_TYPE,
    T3.PHONE
FROM REG_STU_CONTACT T1
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT MIN(PHONE_TYPE) AS PHONE_TYPE, CONTACT_ID 
    FROM REG_CONTACT_PHONE
    WHERE PHONE IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY CONTACT_ID) T2 ON T1.CONTACT_ID = T2.CONTACT_ID
INNER JOIN REG_CONTACT_PHONE T3 ON T2.CONTACT_ID = T3.CONTACT_ID AND T2.PHONE_TYPE = T3.PHONE_TYPE
ORDER BY T1.STUDENT_ID
```

Comment: Which database are you using? MySQL? MS SQL Server? Oracle? Each provides different functions for dealing with this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select A.STUDENT_ID     A.CONTACT_ID   B.TYPE   c.PHONE 
from TableA A
inner join 
    (select MIN(type ) as type, Contact_ID 
    from Tableb
    where phone is not null
    group by contactid) B
on A.contactid = b.contactid
inner join Tableb C 
on B.contactid = c.conatctid and b.type = c.type
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked as far as giving just one phone number per contact, however, it seems to have resulted in random duplicates where the STUDENT_ID, CONTACT_ID, PHONE_TYPE, and PHONE are all the same. This may have been a result of how I adjusted the above query to fit our actual environment. Do you mind taking a look at my query to see if I changed something incorrectly?

Comment: Can you try ?

  select * from tbl
  (select  T1.STUDENT_ID, 
   T1.CONTACT_ID, 
   T2.PHONE_TYPE, 
   T2.PHONE ,
   row_number() over (partition by T1.contactid order by T2.PHONE_TYPE) as  rowno
   FROM REG_STU_CONTACT T1 
 INNER JOIN EG_CONTACT_PHONE T2
 on t1.contactid = t2.contactid
 WHERE PHONE IS NOT NULL 
 ) tbl

 where tbl.rowno = 1

Comment: Sory, had a mistake

This should work


select * from 
 (select T1.STUDENT_ID, T1.CONTACT_ID, T2.PHONE_TYPE, T2.PHONE ,
  row_number() over (partition by T1.contactid order by T2.PHONE_TYPE) as rowno 
   FROM REG_STU_CONTACT T1 INNER JOIN EG_CONTACT_PHONE T2 on t1.contactid = t2.contactid WHERE PHONE IS NOT NULL ) tbl 
   where tbl.rowno = 1